# ToDate paramenter not showing the current date records in SSRS report

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I am using FromDate and ToDate parameter to filter the records in SSRS report. If I choose from date as  1st Oct 2020 and Todate as 15th Oct 2020, then it is showing the records till 14th Oct 2020 even though I have data for 15th Oct 2020.

The query looks like below and really appreciate your support.

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE to_date(created_date) >= '2020-10-01'
AND  to_date(created_date) <= '2020-10-15'
```

Thank you.

Regards,
Viresh

Comment: Your question needs more information, such as some representative data from your table, what the actual query is, where it is being executed and against what version of SQL database

Comment: and tags. I suspect this is Oracle?

Comment: `to_date` still includes the time in Oracle - try `TO_DATE(created_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')`.. "The Oracle TO_DATE SQL function is used to convert a TEXT or NTEXT representation of a date into an Oracle DATETIME value."

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. I used to_date and it is working fine.